# Progress Dialog / Soft keyboard freezes on screen on marshmallow

Tags: android, user-interface, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have used async-task for network operations. My application also has a navigation drawer.

The issue is when my flow comes to my program after network operation,the progress **dialog stuck** on screen. Although i can tap on behind screen control which works fine. 
**soft keyboard also stuck** sometimes on screen.

Actually these are not on the screen; but UI stuck sometimes. This issue is on **MARSHMALLOW**

Comment: Can you please elaborate it more with code?

Comment: you have got ANR?

Comment: protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (!(mTitle.equals(""))) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext, ProgressDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT);
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.setMessage(mTitle);
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

 
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
    }
}

Comment: Dialog doesnot disappear on marshmallow, sometimes.....


Showing it on preExecute and hiding it in postExecute. No, there is no ANR.... as the app is in running state. controls of behind dialog window works fine.